# Parse Server remove object with ACL

Tags: php, parse-platform, acl

I am using Parse server PHP SDK for add and remove object from server.
I am able to add object to the server, however, it shows

> Error: Permission denied for action delete on class.

When I try to remove object from server.

I noticed there is an ACL applied the class, I am not sure if this is reason why the Permission denied.

Does anyone know how to add ACL to the code during the remove action, please?

cheers,

Comment: What is the ACL that you have for this object? Also, check what is the CLP of this class.

Answer (score 0):

A default **ACL**  of public read and write is applied to all classes except for the User class where ACL is public read, user write only.
If you are performing delete on any other class except for the user class and you get that error that means your CLP is denying delete. Go to your Class CPL and check whether delete option is ticked or not.
If you are performing delete on user class you can delete a user only if you are logged in as the user.
If you want to delete without being logged in then use master key.

Comment: Thanks, I aa using master key but still get Permission denied.
However, when I added "true" parameter into the destroy() function and it works.